# Does change of date or inconsistency between date and hwclock affect to ipv4 (inet addr) in ifconfig in linux?

Tags: linux, date, ip, ifconfig

I have trouble that inet addr(ipv4) of eth0 disappears and eth0 interface becomes unavailable.
I'v not waited for refresh but I thought it would not restore itself.

I guess that It Occurs When I Changed the Date by `sudo date MMDDHHmmYYYY.SS`

When I changed the date as 030810102016.00 today(03/08/2021),
IP address disappeared in few minutes (as I thought).

I'v tried it multiple times, and got same results.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS.

Does the change can cause problem in ip?
(especially setting back to past date.)

or, does the inconsistency between date and hwclock can cause that?

Comment: What do you mean "inet addrs of eth0 disappears" sometime? How large are your changes? Tip: use `ntp` to have smooth change of dates. arp and dhcp have cache and they use time to see if they need to refresh them. Some protocols may check time on both ends [SSL]. BTW if you include some more details, the question may be useful for our sister site "serverfault" (link on top right incon)

Comment: Sorry, My poor English made misrepresentation. I mean, inet addr disappeared. that's it. I'm thinking about using ntp, but there is an ambiguous part because I use only local network not connected to internet. Moreover, I don't have experience in ntp.

Answer (score 0):

I checked /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases,
and found that dhcp expired without renew or rebind because of time change (back to past).

```
$ tail -n 30 /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases
    ...
    lease {
      interface "eth0";
    ...
      option dhcp-lease-time 60;
    ...
      renew 2 2021/03/30 02:27:16;
      rebind 2 2021/03/30 02:27:37;
      expire 2 2021/03/30 02:27:45;
    }
```

I think renew and rebind use Universal time in `timedatectl`

However, the reason why wlan0 does not record the data of lease in the file and is not affected by time change is still mystery in my shallow knowledge.